# Can't load all of the page content with phantom

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I just wanted to let you know that i ve tried the solution with setTimeout (before marking my question as DUPLICATE)

The problem is related to the website that i'm scraping 
So when i used phantomJs it only scrape the first part of the web page and not all of the page

I even tried another webscraping tool (APIFY) and it returns the same content

This is the page that i'm scraping [the page that i want to scrape](https://www.articles-epresse.fr/media/894eab75-c642-46a2-a1ba-b240c278ebbc?)

And this is the code that i'm using :

```
var phantom = require("phantom");
    (async function() {
        const instance = await phantom.create();
        const page = await instance.createPage();
        await page.on("onResourceRequested", function(requestData) {
          console.info("Requesting", requestData.url);
        });

        const status = await page.open(
          "https://www.articles-epresse.fr/media/894eab75-c642-46a2-a1ba-b240c278ebbc?"
        );

        const content = await page.property("content");
        console.log(content);
        var $ = cheerio.load(content);
        console.log($("#article319670").attr("href")); // returns undefined 
    //because phantomJs is not reaching the end of the page
        await instance.exit();
      })();
```

PS : i used phantom because the code source of the page is not the same as " inspect element"

Thank You